# How to fix Laravel 7 redirect causing 405 error?

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, eloquent, http-status-code-405

What I am trying to do is after a record has been deleted, redirect back to a certain page with a success message. The error that I am getting is that the redirect is causing a "405 method not allowed error". If I remove the redirect the delete works fine.

**My Delete Method**

```
public function destroy($id){
    $customer = Customer::find($id);
    $customer->delete();
    return redirect()->route('customers.index')->with('success','Customer deleted');
}
```

**Other Redirect Methods I've Tried**

```
return redirect()->action('CustomerController@index')->with('success', 'Customer deleted');
redirect('pages.customers.index')->with('success', 'Customer deleted');
return redirect()->to('/customers')->with('success', 'Customer deleted')->send();
```

**Route Configuration**

`Route::resource('customers', 'CustomerController');`

[image]

**My Index Method**

```
public function index()
{
    $customers = Customer::all();
    return view('pages.customers.index', compact('customers'));
}
```

From what I've read on other posts, the wrong method is being used when redirecting, is there a way I can specify which method to use?

Comment: Could you post the relevant output of `php artisan route:list`?

Comment: For sure, I've added a snapshot of it to the question.

Comment: That's interesting. Can you find our where the exception triggering the 405 originates? Like with [Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) or by temporarily removing the `HttpException` from the [`internalDontReport`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L62) list of Laravel's exception handler?

Comment: Try this.
`return redirect('customers')->with('success', 'Customer deleted');`

Comment: @Dan my handler.php file doesn't have an internalDontReport variable like that example. As for Debugbar I'll have to look into how to integrate that into my project.

Comment: @AdeelTahir that eliminates the 405 error, however, no redirect happens. When I refresh the page manually the record is deleted and I get my success message but it's not redirecting automatically like it should be.

Comment: For this one time you are allowed to modify the vendor file.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems right, try `php artisan route:clear`